# How do I combineLatest an Observable<Observable<T>>?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an `Observable<Observable<String>> c`. I would like to combine each inner `Observable` into one `String` with new-lines. The result should be `Observable<String>`.

There is a [similar discussion for RxJS on GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/1399).

Here is an implementation using `zip`:

```
final Observable<String> d = Observable.zip(c, objects -> Arrays.stream(objects)
    .map(x -> (String)x)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

The problem is that `zip` pairs elements, so if the inner `Observable` objects are of different lengths, then not everything gets shown. I would like to use `combineLatest` instead, but there does not seem to be a matching function:

```
public static <T, R> Observable<R> combineLatest(
    ObservableSource<? extends ObservableSource<? extends T>> sources, 
    Function<? super Object[], ? extends R> zipper)
```

How should I implement this?

---

For example, if I have three observables:

```
// a
Observable.just("Started", "0%", "5%", "10%", "20%", "40%", "95%", "100%", "Finished")

// b 
Observable.just("Started", "0%", "10%", "30%", "40%", "100%", "Finished")

// c
Observable.just("Started", "0%", "20%", "25%", "40%", "70%", "90%", "100%", "Finished")
```

Then the output of my `zip` solution is:

```
---------------------
a: Started
b: Started
c: Started
---------------------
a: 0%
b: 0%
c: 0%
---------------------
a: 5%
b: 10%
c: 20%
---------------------
a: 10%
b: 30%
c: 25%
---------------------
a: 20%
b: 40%
c: 40%
---------------------
a: 40%
b: 100%
c: 70%
---------------------
a: 95%
b: Finished
c: 90%
```

But the desired output is something like:

```
---------------------
a: Started
b: Started
c: Started
---------------------
a: 0%
b: 0%
c: 0%
---------------------
a: 5%
b: 10%
c: 20%
---------------------
a: 10%
b: 30%
c: 25%
---------------------
a: 20%
b: 40%
c: 40%
---------------------
a: 40%
b: 100%
c: 70%
---------------------
a: 95%
b: Finished
c: 90%
---------------------
a: 100%
b: Finished
c: 100%
---------------------
a: Finished
b: Finished
c: Finished
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RxJava2 (and Java 8)

```
c.toList().toObservable()
          .flatMap(t -> 
                  Observable.combineLatest(t, 
                                           objects -> Arrays.stream(objects)
                                                            .map(x ->(String)x).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))))
```

Using RxJava

```
c.toList().flatMap(t -> 
                  Observable.combineLatest(t, 
                                           objects -> Arrays.stream(objects)
                                                            .map(x -> (String)x).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))));
```

I doubt it will do exactly what you want though because it is entirely possible it will "skip" emissions but that's the way `combineLatest` works.

Comment: This seems to be joining in the wrong way. In my `zip` version, each of the inner observables has a row in each of the resulting elements. In this version, each resulting element has all of the rows for one of the inner observables.

Comment: Could you add an example of your inputs and your what you'd like to output?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - the first output only gets shown after the first two observables complete: `a: Finished b: Finished c: Started`

Comment: It does what you requested but like I said it might not do what you want.